# Calculating maximum power of a unknown resistor

Tags: passive-networks

I need to calculate for what value of Rpot, will I get the biggest value of power.

This is the electric scheme:
[image: Electric scheme for my problem] 
The values are: 1=1kΩ, 2=250Ω, =5V.

I have idea how to do it, but I don't know how to get the maximum power at Rpot. Everything else is easy, but I have no idea how to get the power.

Can you give me some advice.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the idea you have? Voltage, U = 5V is irrelevant by the way. Do you know the criteria for maximum power transfer from a voltage supply with output resistance?

Comment: My first idea was to somehow calculate the current or the voltage trough the branch, and from there to calculate the resistance. That proved impossible because, I dont know what is the value of Rpot.

Comment: Try some thought experiments. What is the power if Rpot is zero or if Rpot is infinite? Can you write an equation for the current through Rpot or the voltage across Rpot? Do you know the expressions for power in a resistor given its voltage or current?

Comment: The main problem for me here is that I have no idea, for what power I need to calculate, or for what value of Rpot. I can calculate the power for the values, but there still remains a question is that the biggest value, or there existis a bigger value.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_transfer_theorem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As this sounds like a homework question I'll let you do the actual calculations

**Step 1**: Convert the voltage,U, R1 and R2 into a Thevenin equivalent circuit. (ignore the pot resistor for the time being)

(see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem))

[image]

**Step 2:** Apply the maximum power transfer theorum   (load resistance = source resistance)

**Step3:**  Work out the power in using Ohm's law